# wacom graphire (ET-0405-U) driver for os x el capitan

Tags: osx-el-capitan

I am trying to get my old Wacom Graphire tablet to work on OS X El Capitan. I tried downloading http://www.wacom.com/en-us/support/product-support/drivers (Driver 5.3.3-3 for OS X 10.8, 10.7 & 10.6), but I got a message at the end saying that this is not compatible with my operating system. Any suggestions?

Comment: As this is a tech-support question rather than about graphic design, you're probably best asking on [su] or [apple.se]. As there are no drivers listed for El Capitan i'm guessing it's not officially supported, but there are posts on [su] about other older Wacom tablets working using alternative drivers

Answer (score 3):

Hi I had no pressure sensitivity on my ET-0405-U until I followed this advice:
"I have an ancient Intuos GD-0608-U and I got it to work with El Capitan by installing this driver from Wacom: http://cdn.wacom.com/U/drivers/mac/pro/WacomTablet_6.2.0w4.dmg As the previous user stated the preferences don't work but the pen/stylus does work with default settings..."
from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210735/is-it-possible-to-use-old-wacom-tablet-on-10-11 
Other drivers (5.2.6-5 5.3.6-6 ) gave me a single pressure only as did the newer Bamboo drivers